# Reference for Finite Difference Schemes

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, soft-question, numerical-methods, finite-differences

Is there any place that I can find a list of different PDEs and common finite difference schemes used for each? I have seen tables of finite difference coefficients such as the one here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficients, but I realize that studying convergence of a finite difference scheme is a case by case study. Simply replacing the differential operators in a PDE with any arbitrary finite difference operator will not ensure consistency or stability, let alone tell us anything about the dissipation or dispersion in the scheme. So, my question is, does anybody know of a good reference that lists PDEs (common and not-so-common) and the schemes used to solve each (with explanations of the pros and cons to each scheme)?

I'd like to save some work in the future by having a good reference around.

Comment: Having a CFD background, I know some methods for hyperbolic PDE.
You can take a look at the following Wiki articles for 
[Lax Friedrichmethod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lax%E2%80%93Friedrichs_method)
[Upwind scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upwind_scheme)
[Crank Nicolson method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crank%E2%80%93Nicolson_method)
[Lax wendroff method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lax%E2%80%93Wendroff_method)

Searching for the names on google should give more results.

Comment: For elliptic PDE consider [chapter 1.](ftp://home.oleshkevich.ru/Books/M_Mathematics/MC_Calculus/MCde_Differential%20equations/Knabner%20P.,%20Angerman%20L.%20Numerical%20Methods%20for%20Elliptic%20and%20Parabolic%20Partial%20Differential%20Equations%20%28Springer,%20Texts%20Appl.%20.pdf)

Comment: So, the book that I've been using is *Finite Difference Schemes and Partial Differential Equations* by Strikwerda. It's a good book, and it has everything that you would need for the basic schemes. But say I have some non-linear PDE or I can't find an appropriate scheme in that book. I'm looking for a list that would make finding appropriate schemes easier. Is this something that would be useful, or am I missing something about how people in numerical methods go about these things.

Comment: Do you mean a list that tells you for different specified PDE's which method you need to use and why?

Comment: Yeah. I mean on a case by case basis, I could look at several different books, but it would be nice to have a list that had it all in one place. Is there some kind of encyclopedic reference out there, like maybe a "Handbook" of Schemes?

Comment: Sounds interesting, I will continue searching.

Comment: How about chapter 2 http://homepages.cwi.nl/~haverkor/documents/NumMethPDEs.pdf

Comment: This is good. This is definitely the kind of thing I'm looking for! But it would be nice to go beyond the basics, i.e., with other non-linear PDEs.

Comment: Sorry, this is all i got. Please let me know, if you found a reference.